# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mb_strripos()

Tags: php, wordpress

I use plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/facebook-auto-publish/ for Wordpress, but I got error `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mb_strripos()`.

To check I've created single php file:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

echo mb_strripos("qwert", "w");
?>
```

And I got the same error. In php docs I didn't find what was wrong.

Output of `php -v`:

```
PHP 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.5 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.5, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by 
Zend Technologies
```

Where is I'm mistaken? Thank you

Comment: Did you install `sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring` its does not come as core

Comment: Oh, my bad( Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a plugin that's attempting to call a multibyte string function, `mb_strripos()`. The plugin isn't checking if those functions are available first however.

`mbstring` isn't a default extension in PHP. If you want to use those functions, you must install the extension first. Details on how to do that can be found in the documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php

The approach you take to installation is going to depend on your hosting environment. It may be that you can install the extension yourself; it may be that you have to contact the hosting provider instead. Without knowing your particular setup, I can't make a suggestion.

The plugin really ought to be checking for mbstring support and showing a user friendly error message if it's not available rather than allowing it to trigger an error.